# when I try to update composer I get this error :

Tags: laravel-5

php artisan clear-compiled

[BadMethodCallException]
  Method filter does not exist.

Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error

> [RuntimeException]   Error Output: update [--prefer-source]
>   [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins]
>   [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts]
>   [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose]
>   [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative]
>   [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest]
>   [-i|--interactive] [--] []...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem in the laravel framework and the package version I was trying to install. It worked after installing laravel 5.1.*. You can also change the packages in the composer.json file.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete storage/framework/compiled.php and re-execute composer install/composer update.

Comment: that file doesn't exist in my storage/framework folder.